# Mocking KVO with OCMock

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, key-value-observing, ocmock

I would like to test that Key-Value-Observation is working properly for a class of mine. It has one property, which depends on another. They are set up like so:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSecondProperty {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:
            @"firstProperty",
            nil];
}

- (NSArray *)secondProperty {
    return [self.firstProperty array];
}
```

I want to run a unit test to verify that when `firstProperty` changes, an object bound to `secondProperty` gets a notification. At first I thought I would be able to use `+[OCMockObject observerMock]`, but it looks like that can only be used with `NSNotificationCenter`. What would be the best way to test this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I worked on this for a while after @chrispix's answer inspired me to work in a different direction. I started with this:

```
id objectToObserve = [[TheClassBeingTested alloc] init];

id secondPropertyObserver = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSObject class]];
[[secondPropertyObserver expect] observeValueForKeyPath:@"secondProperty"
                                               ofObject:objectToObserve
                                                 change:OCMOCK_ANY
                                                context:[OCMArg anyPointer]];
[objectToObserve addObserver:secondPropertyObserver
                  forKeyPath:@"secondProperty"
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                     context:NULL];

// Do something to modify objectToObserve's firstProperty    

[secondPropertyObserver verify];
```

When I ran this test code, I got the following message:

```
OCMockObject[NSObject]: unexpected method invoked: isKindOfClass:<??> 
    expected:     observeValueForKeyPath:@"firstProperty" ofObject:
```

I did some investigation and found that the `-isKindOfClass:` call the mock object didn't expect was being passed an `NSKeyValueObservance` class object.

I tried adding the following code to mock a response, but values of `YES` and `NO` both fail with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exceptions with NSKeyValueWillChange in the stack.

```
BOOL returnVal = NO;
[[[secondPropertyObserver stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(returnVal)] isKindOfClass:[OCMArg any]];
```

I stepped more carefully and found that my code wasn't causing this exception - it was while the `autoreleasepool` was being drained. It then dawned on me that I needed to remove the observer. Below is the complete solution, including removing the observer.

```
id objectToObserve = [[TheClassBeingTested alloc] init];

id secondPropertyObserver = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSObject class]];

BOOL returnVal = NO;
[[[secondPropertyObserver stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(returnVal)] isKindOfClass:[OCMArg any]];

[[secondPropertyObserver expect] observeValueForKeyPath:@"secondProperty"
                                               ofObject:objectToObserve
                                                 change:OCMOCK_ANY
                                                context:[OCMArg anyPointer]];

[objectToObserve addObserver:secondPropertyObserver
                  forKeyPath:@"secondProperty"
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                     context:NULL];

// Do something to modify objectToObserve's firstProperty    

[secondPropertyObserver verify];

[objectToObserve removeObserver:secondPropertyObserver
                     forKeyPath:@"secondProperty"];
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's some outcome to `secondProperty` receiving the notification that you can verify, I'd just set it to an actual object and validate the state afterwards. If that's not possible, you could create a partial mock of `secondProperty` and expect the KVO callback:

```
id observedObject = // ...initialize observed class
observedObject.secondProperty = // initialize secondProperty
id mockSecondProperty = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:observedObject.secondProperty];
[[mockSecondProperty expect] observeValueForKeyPath:@"firstProperty" ofObject:observedObject change:OCMOCK_ANY context:OCMOCK_ANY];

observedObject.firstProperty = // modify firstProperty

[mockSecondProperty verify];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for whoever is interested in this: Here's a solution without OCMock.

I simply bind the value that I expect to change to a test property of my unit test class.

In the following example I want the `numberOfPages` property to be updated and to fire KVO notifications when I change the `pages` array.

I declare a `boundInteger` property on my `DocumentTests` class:

```
@interface DocumentTests : SenTestCase 
@property (assign) int boundInteger;
@end
```

Then I implement my test case like so:

```
- (void)testNumberOfPages
{
    Document *doc = [[Document alloc] init];

    [self bind:@"boundInteger" toObject:doc withKeyPath:@"numberOfPages" options:nil];

    doc.pages = arrayOfThreePagesIHaveBuildSomewhereElse;

    STAssertEquals(self.boundInteger, 3, @"Wrong number of pages.");
    STAssertEquals(doc.numberOfPages, 3, @"Wrong number of pages.");

    [self unbind:@"boundInteger"];
}
```

Works fine for me :)