# Why does OCMock partialMock break KVO?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, ocmock

If I have an object that uses KVO to observe a property on some object and then create a partial mock for that observer I no longer receive any notifications. Why is this?

Here's a minimal example:

```
@interface TestPartialMockAndKVO : SenTestCase
@end
@implementation TestPartialMockAndKVO

- (void)test {
    // Should print "Changed!" when foo property is changed
    MyObserver* myObserver = [[[MyObserver alloc] init] autorelease];

    // But with this line, there is no print out
    [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:myObserver];

    [myObserver setFoo:@"change"];
}

@end
```

-

```
@interface MyObserver : NSObject    
@property (copy) NSString* foo;
@end
@implementation MyObserver

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"foo" options:0 context:NULL];
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Changed!");
}

- (void)dealloc { ... }    
@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both KVO and OCMock are doing some little runtime tricks whereby they create a private subclass of your actual class in order to perform their magic. KVO is doing a thing called ["isa-swizzling"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html), and OCMock is creating an object to be the [forwarding target](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-SW27) of your original object.

Each system is sort of off in its own little world, with its own class that has nothing to do with the other. [Mocking KVO with OCMock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9603362) looks similar to your problem. I think you should be able to make this work just by telling your mock to

```
[[myMock expect] observeValueForKeyPath:@"foo"
                               ofObject:myObserver
                                 change:[OCMArg any]
                                context:[OCMArg any]];
```